# timestamp difference in bigquery with date

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, timestamp-with-timezone

I have used Dataiku to transfer 40 GB of data from snowflake to big query. Somehow timestamp value changed my dates completely

Instead of `2021-06-30 00:00:00 UTC` the copied timestamp value is `2021-06-29 22:00:00 UTC`

I am looking for a bigquery solution to cast this into the correct timestamp as loading the data again is not possible.

Can someone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution

`SELECT TIMESTAMP_ADD(Day_Sts, INTERVAL 120 MINUTE) AS Day_Sts,* except (Day_Sts)`